# Writing Array LineWise to a .txt file?

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio, listview

Here is a small part of my program. here i am basically writing a .txt file when  the button - 'HideItBtn' is clicked. in this piece of code first the.txt file is created then the value of the ListView SubItem - 'Folder path' is stored in a string array and that array is used to write the text file.

```
  private void HideItBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string[] strArray = new string[500];
            int i = 0;
            //Creat Hide.bat and write in it !
            StreamWriter hide = new StreamWriter(HideNameTxt.Text + ".txt");
            for (int j = 1; j < FolderList.Items[i].SubItems.Count; j++)
            {
                ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem cur = FolderList.Items[i].SubItems[j];

                strArray[i] = cur.Text;
                hide.WriteLine("attrib \" + strArray[i] + "\" + Environment.NewLine);

                i++;
            }
            hide.Close();
}
```

Now the problem:

i run  my application and select 3 folders from which show up in the ListView !
But the output .txt file only contains :

```
attrib "C:\Users\Sand\Desktop\nf"
```

Non of the other folder r
 listed ! i added -"Environment.NewLine" at the end of .WriteLine ! but nothing happened ! Please Help ! Thanks !

Comment: what should the text file contain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have two `for` loops, not one.  Currently you're incrementing `i` at the end of your for loop, but you've only written one of the sub items, not all of them.  You need to have a loop that goes through all items, and *another loop* to go through all sub-items.

```
private void HideItBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (StreamWriter hide = new StreamWriter(HideNameTxt.Text + ".txt"))
        for (int i = 0; i < FolderList.Items.Count; i++)
            for (int j = 1; j < FolderList.Items[i].SubItems.Count; j++)
            {
                ListViewSubItem cur = FolderList.Items[i].SubItems[j];
                hide.WriteLine("attrib \"" + cur.Text + "\"" 
                    + Environment.NewLine);
            }
}
```

Comment: That Worked Flawlessly ! :) Thanks ! :D